# condicional executar query mongo

Tags: php, base-de-datos, mongodb, funciones, condiciones

Tengo el siguiente código, y quiero saber si hay alguna función de mongodb que devuelva true o false dependiendo de si la query se ha ejecutado correctamente o no.

```
public function removepopup($id){
    $collection = $this->connect()->deleteOne(['_id' => new MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID( $id )]);
}
```

Comment: Pon el código de la función deleteOne(); si no, no podremos ayudarte.

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/php-library/v1.2/reference/method/MongoDBCollection-deleteOne/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El método deleteOne(), por lo que he leido en la documentación te devuelve un Objeto del tipo MongoDB\DeleteResult,  https://docs.mongodb.com/php-library/v1.2/reference/write-result-classes/#phpclass.MongoDB\DeleteResult . Se utiliza para encapsular en objeto PHP http://php.net/class.mongodb-driver-writeresult . Bien, el objeto php tiene unos métodos, escribiré un código a ver si te sirve, basandome en el método: http://php.net/manual/es/mongodb-driver-writeresult.getdeletedcount.php

```
public function removepopup($id){
    $collection = $this->connect()->deleteOne(['_id' => new MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID( $id )]);
     if($collection->getDeletedCount() == 0){
          //No se ha eliminado ninguna fila
          return false;
     }
     return true;
}
```